# Does scrollIntoView scroll to hidden DIV's even when scroll bars have been turned off (i.e overflow:hidden)?

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I'm currently working on implementing scrollIntoView in a test tool. I noticed that element.scrollIntoView() scrolls to hidden elements (DIV's) even when the overflow of their containers is hidden (scroll bars turned off). Is this behavior of scrollIntoView expected? I don't see any articles/documents that answers this question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow says, _“The JavaScript Element.scrollTop property may be used to scroll an HTML element even when overflow is set to hidden.”_ - so I don’t see why it should be different with any other method of scrolling an element to a certain position, or in this case, to scroll a certain descendant element into view.

Comment: I was of the impression that scrollTop would be zero when the overflow is hidden (even if elements are overflowing). This is because the scrollbars are hidden in that case.